# How can i list all databases in an Axure subscription and filter using Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell

I am currently getting databases details individually by using

```
$dbs = (az sql db list --resource-group rg1 --server myservername | ConvertFrom-Json).
```

There are a few databases so can I list all databases in a subscription and filter the names for example:
where names like 'Crm%' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `az sql db list` you used is [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli), not [Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/?view=azps-5.7.0), but `ConvertFrom-Json` is a PowerShell command, I don't recommend you to mix them together, sometimes it will cause some issues, so if you want to use PowerShell to do that, just use the Azure PowerShell command [`Get-AzSqlDatabase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/get-azsqldatabase?view=azps-5.7.0).

Make sure you have [installed the `Az` powershell module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-5.7.0) and login with `Connect-AzAccount`, then use the script below, it will list all the databases with the name like `jos*`, `*` is the wildcard.

```
$servers = Get-AzSqlServer
foreach($server in $servers){
    Get-AzSqlDatabase -ServerName $server.ServerName -ResourceGroupName $server.ResourceGroupName | Where-Object {$_.DatabaseName -like 'jos*'}
}
```

[image]